# How to obtain images (media manager) path from Jumi?

Tags: php, joomla1.5, jumi

I have the following Jumi code in Joomla 1.5

[image]

Now I want to refer the image location from my media files `/home/content/49/6333949/html/images/posters` which is `Media/images/posters`.

Are there any PHP variables to get this full path without hardcoding it?

Comment: Don't you think that this outdated piece of software should run down /dev/null? If used in the internet any site using Joomla 1.5 is a well documented security risk.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the root path of a joomla website, You can use the following stuff :

"JURI::base()" : is a methode for get the HTTP path of you project;
"JPATH_BASE" : is a constant to get the real path of you project;

Comment: What is "my project"?

Comment: Another term : Your webiste

Comment: Yes it's PHP .
`<?php print JURI::base();?> //will display the http path and
<?php print JPATH_BASE;?> //will display the folder path.`
Just try it